# I need help appending input to my empty list by the amount of times of value

Tags: python, list, user-input

```
num_of_floats = int(input())
data_nums = []
user = float(input())
x=0
while x <= num_of_floats:
    x+=1
    data_nums.append(user)
print(data_nums)
```

inputs:
5
30
50
10
100
65
outputs:
[30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0]
i was expecting for the out put to be
[30.0, 50.0, 10.0, 100.0, 60.0]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the logic of the code. Where the code says `user = float(input())`, what is the purpose of that? **How many times** should that happen - only once, or repeatedly for `num_of_floats` times? Therefore, should it be inside the loop, or outside? Is it?

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
num_of_floats = int(input("enter number of inputs "))
data_nums = []

x=0
while x < num_of_floats:
    
    user = float(input("Enter input "))
    data_nums.append(user)
    x+=1
print(data_nums)
```

The issue was you were only collecting the second input. By putting the input inside the loop it collects a new input each time. Plus you should move the x+=1 to the end and make it only x < num_of_floats.